# RecyclerView is not working in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am using NestedScrollView in tab layout and when I implemented RecyclerView in NestedScrollView 2 problems occur:

1. Toolbar is not hiding.
2. RecyclerView in not scrolling smoothly.

Here is my Code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:background="#fafafa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: do you have toolbar in NestedScrollView because as per your code you add your RecyclerView with  android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"

Answer (score 1):

use `recylerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` to make your scrolling smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate layout files for views and try. And include those into the list view.

```
<LinuearLayout ..>
  <include layout="@layout/cv1"/>
  <include layout="@layout/rv1"/>
  <include layout="@layout/rv2"/>
  <include layout="@layout/rv3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is just a clue to you. I did solve similar issues long back in past. Please try experimenting with this clue.